# XSLT Convert XML to HTML with dynamic rows and columns

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

My XML format is as follows:

```
<Items>
    <Item name="Item1">
        <Label>Label 1</Label>
    </Item> 
    <Item name="Item2">
        <Label>Label 2</Label>
    </Item>
    <ColumnBreak></ColumnBreak>
    <Item name="Item3">
        <Label>Label 3</Label>
    </Item>
    <Item name="Item4">
        <Label>Label 4</Label>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I want to transform it into an HTML in a way that `<ColumnBreak>` acts as a row/column converter. With the above sample, the expected HTML div output is:

```
          Column 1       Column 2
          --------       --------
Row 1 |   Label 1        Label 3
Row 2 |   Label 2        Label 4
```

If, for example, `<ColumnBreak>` is set after Item3 in the XML, the resulting div should have 3 rows and 2 columns, with the 2nd column only showing Label 4.

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? Does `ColumnBreak` appear after same number of `Item` elements?

Comment: @AniketV yes, it appears after same number of elements

Comment: Are you using XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @AniketV Version 1

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with a simple code. Used HTML table instead of div.

```
 <xsl:template match="/Items">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="round(12 div (count(ColumnBreak) + 1))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="round(count(Item) div (count(ColumnBreak) + 1))" />
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="Item[position() &lt;= $rows]">
        <xsl:variable name="x" select="position() mod $rows"/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="../Item[position() mod $rows = $x]">
              <td style="col-md-{$cols}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
 </xsl:template>
```